# JSONP post data to other domain

Tags: jsonp

I have tried to find the answer to this by searching for a while now but I'm not finding what I need.

So I have these input boxes.

```
  <div>
  Kontaktuppgifter<br>
  <input class="double" type="text" name="customer_firstName" placeholder="Förnamn" />
  <input class="double" type="text" name="customer_surName" placeholder="Efternamn" />
  <input class="double" type="email" name="customer_email" placeholder="Epost" />
  <input class="double" type="tel" name="customer_cellnr" placeholder="Mobilnummer" />
  </div>

  <div>      
  Adressuppgifter<br>
  <input type="text" name="customer_adress" placeholder="BostadsAdress" />
  <input type="text" name="customer_zipcode" placeholder="{{postal_code_label}}" />
  <input type="text" name="customer_city" placeholder="Ort" />
  <input type="text" name="customer_country" placeholder="Land" />
  </div>

  <div>
  Garantispecifika uppgfiter<br>
  <input type="text" name="customer_housenr" placeholder="Fastighetsbeteckning" />
  <input type="text" name="customer_persnumber" placeholder="Personnummer" />
  </div>

  <div>
  Företagsspecifika uppgifter - Fylls bara i av företag<br>
  <input type="text" name="customer_companyName" placeholder="Företagsnamn" />
  <input type="text" name="customer_Orgnr" placeholder="Organisationsnummer" />
  <input id="send_message" class="button secondary" type="submit" value="Registrera Garanti" onclick="postFrom(this)"/>
  </div>
```

Now I want to send all data via **JSONP**.

I got it to work with one, attribute **'customer_name=json'**

How should I concatenate everything to I can send it to my handler?

Is **data:** the only tag i can use or how should I structure the call?

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'http://www.mypage.com/offerthandler.ashx',
   crossDomain: true,
   data: 'customer_name=json',
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(responseData, jsonobj) {
   alert('POST Successfull.');

},
error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('POST failed.');
}
 });
```

Should I go for a

```
 data: 'customer_firstName=$('[name="customer_firstName"]').val() + 
        customer_surName=$('[name="customer_surName"]').val()
```

and so on or how am I to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be so insert  tags give the form an id and serialize the form.

Example

```
 <form id="myform">

 Kontaktuppgifter<br>
 <input class="double" type="text" name="customer_firstName" placeholder="Förnamn" />
 <input class="double" type="text" name="customer_surName" placeholder="Efternamn" />
 <input class="double" type="email" name="customer_email" placeholder="Epost" />
 <input class="double" type="tel" name="customer_cellnr" placeholder="Mobilnummer" />
 </from>
```

And now javascript!

```
   var datavariable = $("#myform").serialize();

$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://yoururl.com',
crossDomain: true,
data: datavariable ,
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(responseData, jsonobj) {
    alert('POST Successfull.');

},
```